# Spring Jpa Data , Pageable , Pagerequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA DATA in my project. I wanna make my data pageble. I have already add Pageable to my repository method. But it shows error something like that:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have to provide at least one
>   property to sort by! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have to
>   provide at least one property to sort by!
>         org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.<init>(Sort.java:92)
>         org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.<init>(Sort.java:80)
>         org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest.<init>(PageRequest.java:52)
>         com.datum.fnd.controller.rest.NodeRestController.getNodes(NodeRestController.java:44)
>         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method).....

I want to share my codes with you. Please look over following codes. I haven't find where I did mistake

**My @Repository class:**

```
@Query(value = "select new com.datum.fnd.domain.Node(c.idNode, c.name,c.address, c.description, c.point) from Node c")
List<Node> getNodesByPage(Pageable pageable);
```

**My Service class:**

```
public interface NodeService extends DefaultService<Node, Long> {
    List<Node> getUnboundedNodes();

    List<Node> getNodes(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**My ServiceImpl class:**

```
@Service
public class NodeServiceImpl implements NodeService {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(NodeServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private NodeRepository nodeRepository;

@Autowired
private ChannelNodeRepository channelNodeRepository;

@Override
public Node create(Node node) {
    return nodeRepository.save(node);
}


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Node> list() {
    return nodeRepository.selectAll();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Node> getNodes(Pageable pageable) {
    return nodeRepository.getNodesByPage(pageable);
}
```

**My Controller class:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page/{last_item}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Node> getNodes(@PathVariable(value = "last_item") int last_item) {
    LOG.info("Retrieve all nodes");

    PageRequest page_req = new PageRequest(0, last_item, Direction.DESC);
    return nodeService.getNodes(page_req);
}
```

And when I try to call "http://localhost:8088/FNDWEB/rest/node/page/50" it shows the above-mentioned error.

Comment: The PageRequest constructor that you're using seems to need a fourth non-null argument http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction-java.lang.String...-

Comment: When I remove " Direction.DESC" from my PageRequest it works

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Exception message and [documentation of PageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.9.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction-java.lang.String...-) should make your problem clear. If you provide `Sort.Direction` to `PageRequest` constructor, you have to provide also at least one property name (according to which entities should be sorted).

For example:

```
PageRequest page_req = new PageRequest(0, last_item, Direction.DESC, "idNode");
```

Answer (score 5):

PageRequest constructors are deprecated. Use the PageRequest.of instead.

```
public static PageRequest of(int page, int size) {
    return of(page, size, Sort.unsorted());
}

public static PageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort sort) {
    return new PageRequest(page, size, sort);
}

public static PageRequest of(int page, int size, Direction direction, String... properties) {
    return of(page, size, Sort.by(direction, properties));
}
```